# Apache httpd not enforcing cipher order

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I have an httpd server with the following options

```
SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!P
SK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA'
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets off
```

But the cipher order is not enforced.

E.g., by running `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers` I get

```
443/tcp open   https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|   TLSv1.3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
```

How can I force the cipher order?

Comment: Check [apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html): *"To specify which ciphers to use, one can either specify all the Ciphers, one at a time, **[or use aliases to specify the preference and order for the ciphers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#table1)**"*, I think that's what you are looking for.